# How to increment count by concatenating with text in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have looked at [mongoose-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sequence) Plugin, but it can store only in Number format and the counter will start from 0.

I need to create a custom id (mycustomID) which is unique like : ABCD1001. 
ABCD is the prefix value. My counter will start from 1001.

I was expecting to achieve this by using schema.pre("save"). I'm new to Mongoose. Can someone provide any info regarding how to achieve this?

Here is my schema

```
var bookSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true},
  isbn: { type: String},
  prefix: {type: String},
  mycustomID: {type: String, unique: true},
  author: { type: String, required: true},
  status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch last inserted value from DB using command below, so that you will get last customId.
Just convert that customId using `previousCustomId.replace( /^\D+/g, '')` and increment it.

```
bookSchema.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1, function(err, data) {
    var previousCustomId = data[0].mycustomID;  //Make sure it will return data object or data array
    var currentCustomId = parseInt(previousCustomId.replace( /^\D+/g, '')) + 1;

    //Your next entry will be here

})
```